# Is this a correct way to get a bitmap's size before decoding it into memory?

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I know I can use these ways to get the Bitmap's size:

```
bitmap.getAllocationByteCount();              //API 19
bitmap.getByteCount();                        //API 12
bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();    //earlier version
```

But This all need a Bitmap object which mean I need to decode the bitmap into memory before, this may case `OOM` Exception. So I use this way to get the size before I can get Bitmap object:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bitmapPath, options);
int picWidth = options.outWidth;
int picHeight = options.outHeight;
int size = 4 * picHeight * picWidth;    //Byte
```

I think it cost 32 bits per pixel because Android decode bitmap use RGB_8888 default.

Is this a correct way or is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the bitmap configuration with [BitmapFactory.Options.inPreferredConfig](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPreferredConfig).  This will allow you to specify a configuration where you know for sure how many bytes per pixel will be occupied by the Bitmap.  I believe RGB_8888 is the default.

You can probably not 100% reliably prevent an OOM on a bitmap decode since you don't have a guarantee for a set amount of *contiguous* free space in memory for the allocation of the Bitmap.  But you can certainly adjust your sample size and config to reduce the load.

Answer (score -1):

Just create a File object with the path to the Bitmap. Then get file.length() to get the file size.

e.g. File bitmap = new File(pathToBitmap);

bitmap.length();

You'll have to put a try/catch clause as required.

Comment: The bitmap size I want is not the file size but the Bitmap Object size in the memory, it might be larger.